# Solver timeout within loop using z3 Python API

Tags: python, z3

Per an earlier suggestion, I'm trying to set early timeout for a solver while using z3Py.

Again, without all the particulars, this is what I'm attempting:

```
for bits in range(A, B, incrmt)
    s = Solver();
    s.set("timeout", 30) #30, 3000, 30000, 60000 no change
    s.add(some constraints)
    if(s.check() == sat):
        print "Sat, %d," %(bits)
    else:
        print "Sat Unknown, %d," %(bits)
        break
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Essentially, timeout never occurs (even with ridiculously small times in ms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Z3 on Linux or FreeBSD? There was a bug related to timers on these platforms.
I fixed the problem, but it is not part of the official release yet.
See the following post for more details.

- [how to set timeout for z3_solver using C-API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943794/how-to-set-timeout-for-z3-solver-using-c-api)

Comment: Technically yes (Mac OS X).  I'll let you know how it works out.