# Error using timeout option with Solverfor("QF_LIA")

Tags: z3, z3py

I have the following code

```py
s = SolverFor("QF_LIA")
s.set("timeout", 1000)
#added when edited
s.check()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
    s.set("timeout", 1000)

    line 6438, in set
    Z3_solver_set_params(self.ctx.ref(), self.solver, p.params)

    line 3654, in Z3_solver_set_params_elems.Check(a0)

    line 1378, in Check
    raise self.Exception(self.get_error_message(ctx, err))
```

What am I doing wrong here? thx for the help!

**EDIT**

I added s.check (), could you check if you get a error with this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34786270/1911064)

The following example works for me without error:

```
from z3 import *

s = SolverFor("QF_LIA")
s.set("timeout", 1000)

print(z3.get_version_string())
```

Output:

```
python.exe -VV
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

python.exe test.py
4.8.5
```

Comment: Hi thx for the help, but i have the same version as you and I get always the same error. Do you know why i get this error? the only thing that it's different is that you are using 64 bits python.

Comment: Could you check if you add s.check() you get a error, please?

Comment: Perhaps you have combined Z3 32-bit binaries with 64-bit Python? That does not work.

Comment: in that case, you have the same problem as me... i tried without the s.check() and it worked for me too, but if I add the s.chech() i get that error. Do you know why?

Comment: `s.check()` does not result in an error in my tests. Something must be wrong with your installation, I'm afraid.